# Pitfalls of using two persistent store coordinators for efficient background updates

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, sqlite, core-data

I am searching for the best possible way to update a fairly large core-data based dataset in the background, with as little effect on the application UI (main thread) as possible.

There's some good material available on this topic including:

- [Session 211 from WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) (Core Data Performance Optimization and Debugging, from around 25:30 onwards)
- [Importing Large Data Sets from objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data.html)
- [Common Background Practices from objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/common-background-practices.html) (Core Data in the Background)
- [Backstage with Nested Managed Object Contexts](http://floriankugler.com/blog/2013/5/11/backstage-with-nested-managed-object-contexts)

Based on my research and personal experience, the best option available is to effectively use two separate core-data stacks that only share data at the database (SQLite) level. This means that we need two separate `NSPersistentStoreCoordinators`, each of them having it's own `NSManagedObjectContext`. With write-ahead logging enabled on the database (default from iOS 7 onwards), the need for locking could be avoided in almost all cases (except when we have two or more simultaneous writes, which is not likely in my scenario).

In order to do efficient background updates and conserve memory, one also needs to process data in batches and periodically save the background context, so the dirty objects get stored to the database and flushed from memory. One can use the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` that gets generated at this point to merge the background changes into the main context, but in general you don't want to update your UI immediately after a batch has been saved. You want to wait until the background job is completely done and than refresh the UI (recommended in both the WWDC session and objc.io articles). This effectively means that the application main context remains out of sync with the database for a certain time period.

All this leads me to my main question, which is, **what can go wrong, if I changed the database in this manner, without immediately telling the main context to merge changes?** I'm assuming it's not all sunshine an roses.

One specific scenario that I have in my head is, what happens if a fault needs to be fulfilled for an object loaded in the main context, if the background operation has in between deleted that object from the database? Can this for instance happen on a NSFetchedResultsController based table view that uses a batchSize to fetch objects incrementally into memory? I.e., an object that has not yet been fully fetched gets deleted but than we scroll up to a point where the object needs to get loaded. Is this a potential problem? Can other things go wrong? I'd appreciate any input on this matter.

Comment: Specifically where are you seeing performance problems now during your import? What do the Core Data probes in Instruments tell you? I deal with a very similar scenario every day in one of my applications, with a VERY LARGE data set that is being imported and merged while the UI is active. It can be done, and it can be done performantly without mulitple PSCs or stores.

Comment: It's not an import, it's an update, meaning that existing data can change (including being deleted). The performance issues were pretty much those described in the articles and talk I've liked, and are actually not even the main problem here. I already have a solution that uses a background context only (vs also a new PSC) and the performance impact on the main thread isn't that bad. But even that doesn't prevent the problem I outlined above. If I save the background context in batch and do not merge changes immediately when a batch completes the database and UI context get out of sync.

Comment: OK, and are you using one NSPersistentStore, or two?

Comment: One NSPersistentStore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question!

> I.e., an object that has not yet been fully fetched gets deleted but
>   than we scroll up to a point where the object needs to get loaded. Is
>   this a potential problem?

Unfortunately it'll cause problems. A following exception will be thrown:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xc544570 <x-coredata://(...)>'
```

[This blog post](http://thermal-core.com/2013/09/07/in-defense-of-core-data-part-I.html) (section titled "How to do concurrency with Core Data?") might be somewhat helpful, but it doesn't exhaust this topic. I'm struggling with the same problems in an app I'm working on right now and would love to read a write-up about it.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that article as well. The suggestion given in there, translated into my example case would essentially mean, that you shouldn't touch any objects in the background job, if they could be fetched by the feted results controller. Not really ideal.

Comment: I'm not sure this problem can be avoided by other means than immediate merge if some objects were deleted in the background context. Please keep me posted if you stumble on a better solution.

Comment: Actually, if the "background" contexts are children of the one driving the NSFetchedResultsController, you would be fine until you pushed the changes from the children into the parent.

Comment: @quellish: They can't be nested, because they're from different persistent store coordinators: `This means that we need two separate NSPersistentStoreCoordinators, each of them having it's own NSManagedObjectContext. `

Answer (score 3):

Based on your question, comments, and my own experience, it seems the larger problem you are trying to solve is:
1. Using an NSFetchedResultsController on the main thread with thread confinement
2. Importing a large data set, which will insert, update, or delete managed objects in a context.
3. The import causes large merge notifications to be processed by the main thread to update the UI.
4. The large merge has several possible effects:
   - The UI gets slow, or too busy to be usable. This may be because you are using [beginUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates)/[endUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/endUpdates) to update a tableview in your [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), and you have a LOT of animations queing up because of the large merge. 
   - Users can run into "Could not fulfill fault" as they try to access a faulted object which has been removed from the store. The managed object context thinks it exists, but when it goes to the store to fulfill the fault the fault it's already been deleted. If you are using [reloadData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData) to update a tableview in your NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, you are more likely to see this happen than when using beginUpdates/endUpdates.

The approach you are trying to use to solve the above issues is:
- Create two NSPersistentStoreCoordinators, each attached to the same NSPersistentStore or at least the same NSPersistentStore SQLite store file URL.
- Your import occurs on NSManagedObjectContext 1, attached to NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 1, and executing on some other thread(s). Your NSFetchedResultsController is using NSManagedObjectContext 2, attached to NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 2, running on the main thread.
- You are moving the changes from NSManagedObjectContext 1 to 2

You will run into a few problems with this approach. 
- An [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator_Class/NSPersistentStoreCoordinator.html) [job](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001650-SW4) is to mediate between it's *attached* NSManagedObjectContexts and it's attached stores. In the multiple-coordinator-context scenario you are describing, changes to the underlying store by NSManagedObjectContext 1 which cause a change in the SQLite file will not be seen by NSPersistentStoreCoordinator 2 and it's context. 2 does not know that 1 changed the file, and you will have "Could not fulfill fault" and other exciting exceptions.
- You will still, at some point, have to put the changed NSManagedObjects from the import into NSManagedObjectContext 2. If these changes are large, you will still have UI problems and the UI will be out of sync with the store, potentially leading to "Could not fulfill fault".
- In general, because NSManagedObjectContext 2 is not using the same NSPersistentStoreCoordinator as NSManagedObjectContext 1, you are going to have problems with things being out of sync. This isn't how these things are intended to be used together. If you import and save in NSManagedObjectContext 1, NSManagedObjectContext 2 is immediately in a state not consistent with the store.

Those are SOME of the things that could go wrong with this approach. Most of these problems will become visible when firing a fault, because that accesses the store. You can read more about how this process works in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001202), while the [Incremental Store Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/IncrementalStorePG/ImplementationStrategy/ImplementationStrategy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010706-CH2-SW8) describes the process in more detail. The SQLite store follows the same process that an incremental store implementation does.

Again, the use case you are describing - getting a ton of new data, executing [find-Or-Create](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) on the data to create or update managed objects, and deleting "stale" objects that may in fact be the majority of the store - is something I have dealt with every day for several years, seeing all of the same problems you are. There are solutions - even for imports that change 60,000 complex objects at a time, and even using thread confinement! - but that is outside the scope of your question.
(Hint: Parent-Child contexts don't need merge notifications).

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on the matter and basically confirming my suspicions. Parent-Child contexts are the simplest path to take, but creating a child context of the main thread did have a noticeable performance impact on the UI (see http://bit.ly/14ManfK). Also, with child contexts you can't really easily prevent UI updates from occurring immediately after you save a batch of objects in the background. To prevent the faulting issues I was considering just making deleted objects for deletion and not actually deleting them immediately. The actual deletion would happen just before the UI update.

Comment: @MatejBukovinski: I don't know how much data you have, but you could probably move actual deleting from the persistent store to `applicationDidEnterBackground:`. In the `UI` you could just check if `isDeleted` flag is false (something similar is common in server-side programming, but there the data is usually just kept in the DB indefinitely). Not sure if I'm not reinventing the wheel right now.

Comment: Do not use parent-child contexts for background updates, they are not intended for that. Your background context will block the main context causing even worse performance.

Comment: @malhal that is absolutely incorrect. There is no reason to use a main queue context nor is there a reason to perform blocking operations on anything but the queue managing a persistent store.

Comment: The OP is correct to use 2 persistent coordinators, that is what Apple recommend in their sample: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Earthquakes/Introduction/Intro.html His concern is valid about faulting an object which has been deleted, this would previously exception but is fixed in iOS 10. The funny thing is when they resolved this they also now support a background context using the same coordinator as the main context. So lots of new things happening.

Comment: @malhal If you read the description: "Earthquakes shows how to use a second Core Data stack to fetch data on a background queue." Apple sample code is intended to illustrate specific concepts rather than best practices. "Earthquakes", at this time, shows how to use two `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`s *with parent child contexts*. "ThreadedCoreData" on the other hand does so *without* two. Multiple contexts sharing a single PSC has always been available.

Comment: I think what's happened is "ThreadedCoreData" was created before concurrency types, then "Earthquakes" was created to take advantage of private queue concurrency and performBlock. Hopefully there will be a new sample for iOS 10 where only 1 PSC is needed now and querying data while it is being edited should be safer.

Comment: @malhal No. "Earthquakes" is based on "ThreadedCoreData". Querying data "while it is being edited" has always been safe with a single persistent store coordinator and parent-child contexts. Their queues are serial.

Comment: "Earthquakes" does not use parent-child contexts, those are not designed for background imports. The last paragraph on the readme explains what they are for but they are not used in this project: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Earthquakes/Listings/README_md.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014547-README_md-DontLinkElementID_11

Comment: @malhal You seem to misunderstand. Private queue contexts are designed for the exactly that - performing work on a private queue. "ThreadedCoreData" shows the use of parent-child contexts. "Earthquakes" shows using multiple persistent stores. They demonstrate two different ways of accomplishing the same thing. Multiple persistent stores can certainly be used with contexts that have parent-child relationships. Parent-child contexts use that relationship to communicate changes.

Comment: Earlier you had said "Earthquakes shows how to use two NSPersistentStoreCoordinators with parent-child contexts" I was just letting you know it doesn't. And by the way, neither does "ThreadedCoreData". The sample that demonstrates parent-child contexts is called CoreDataBooks. I'm guessing maybe you are mean something different when you speak of parent child contexts.

Comment: @malhal , all of the contexts in those applications support parent-child relationships.

Answer (score 3):

Two Persistent Store Coordinators (pscs) is certainly the way to go with large datasets. File locking is faster than the locking within core data.

There's no reason you couldn't use the background psc to create thread confined NSManagedObjectContexts in which each is created for each operation you do in the background. However, instead of letting core data manage the queueing you now need to create NSOperationQueues and/or threads to manage the operations based on what you're doing in the background. NSManagedObjectContexts are free and not expensive. Once you do this you can hang onto your NSManagedObjectContext and only use it during that one operation and/or threads life time and build as many changes as you want and wait until the end to commit them and merge them to the main thread how ever you decide. Even if you have some main thread writes you can still at crucial points in your operations life time refetch/merge back into your threads context.

Also it's important to know that if you're working on large sets of data don't worry about merging contexts so as long as you aren't touching something else. For example if you have class A and class B and you have two seperate opertions/threads to work on them and they have no direct relationship you do not have to merge the contexts if one changes you can keep on rolling with the changes. The only major need for merging background contexts in this fashion is if there are direct relationships faulting. It would be better to prevent this though through some sort of serialization whether it be NSOperationQueue or what ever else. So feel free to work away on different objects in the background just be careful about their relationships.

I've worked on a large scale core data projects and had this pattern work very well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this is the best core data scenario you can work with. Almost no Main UI staleness, and easy background management of your data. When you want to tell the Main Context (and maybe a currently running `NSFetchedResultsController`) you listen for save notifications of the backgroundContext like this:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
      addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadFetchedResults:)
      name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
      object:backgroundObjectContext];
```

Then, you can merge changes, *but waiting for the Main Thread context to catch them before saving*. When you receive the `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification` notification the changes are not yet saved. Hence the `performBlockAndWait` is mandatory, so the Main context gets the changes and then the `NSFetchedResultsController` updates its values correctly.

```
-(void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext*moc=[notification object];
    if ([moc isEqual:backgroundObjectContext]) 
    {
        // Delete caches of fethcedResults if you have a deletion
        if ([[theNotification.userInfo objectForKey:NSDeletedObjectsKey] count]) {
            [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:nil];
         }
        // Block the background execution of the save, and merge changes before
        [managedObjectContext performBlockandWait:^{
            [managedObjectContext 
            mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        }];
    }
}
```

There is a pitfall no one has noticed. **You can get the save notification before the background context has actually saved the object you want to merge**. If you want to avoid problems by a faster Main Context asking for an object that has not been saved yet by the background context, you should (you **really** should) call `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` **before** any background save. Then you are safe to call the `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`. This will ensure that the merge receives a valid permanent Id for merging.